Getting RuntimeError: view size is not compatible with input tensor's size and stride while using mps
RuntimeError: view size is not compatible with input tensor's size and stride (at least one dimension spans across two contiguous subspaces). Use .reshape(...) instead.
Getting this error only while using mps and not cpu

fine_tuned_decoder_path = "/path/fine_tuned_decoder"
model = VisionEncoderDecoderModel.from_encoder_decoder_pretrained(
    encoder_pretrained_model_name_or_path="google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k",
    decoder_pretrained_model_name_or_path=fine_tuned_decoder_path,
    tie_encoder_decoder=True,
    cache_dir="/path/datasets/"+"models"  # Directory for caching models
)
os.environ["WANDB_MODE"] = "disabled"

# Set batch size and number of training epochs
BATCH_SIZE = 16
TRAIN_EPOCHS = 5

# Define the output directory for storing training outputs
output_directory = os.path.join("path", "captioning_outputs")

# Check if MPS is available
device = torch.device("mps" if torch.backends.mps.is_available() else "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Move your model to the correct device
model.to(device)

# Set mixed precision and device handling
fp16 = False  # Disable fp16 entirely
mixed_precision = None  # Disable mixed precision (default)

# Training Arguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=output_directory,
    per_device_train_batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    do_train=True,
    num_train_epochs=TRAIN_EPOCHS,
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    use_cpu=False,  # Ensure you're not using CPU
    dataloader_pin_memory=False,
    fp16=fp16,  # Disable fp16 if using MPS
    bf16=False,  # Disable bf16 if using MPS
    optim="adamw_torch",  # Use AdamW Torch optimizer (more stable with mixed precision)
    gradient_checkpointing=False,  # Disable gradient checkpointing if necessary
    logging_dir=os.path.join(output_directory, 'logs'),
    report_to="none",  # Disable reporting
    
)

# Use the Trainer with the model on the correct device
trainer = Trainer(
    processing_class=feature_extractor,  # Tokenizer
    model=model,  # Model to train
    args=training_args,  # Training arguments
    train_dataset=train_dataset,  # Training dataset
    data_collator=default_data_collator  # Data collator
)
# Start the training process
trainer.train()

Tried setting use_cpu=True, it works fine but not with mps

There is a known issue with PyTorch 2.5.
You can read more about it here.
One solution is to download the source code, modify the two files as described by malfet, and then compile the source code. This issue is expected to be resolved in PyTorch 2.6.
However, the simplest solution I found was to install the nightly versions of PyTorch:
pip install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu
Best regards,
--KC
